# Python and Google Assistant : name not defined

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with two pieces of python code. Both are exactly the same (Copy/Paste) but the second code doesn't work.

I'm trying to build a personnal assistant that can start Google's Assistant on demand. 
It works perfectly... in English. But I also want French. So I copied the code for English into another file and called it French.
When I ask the assistant to start the assistant (in French) he fails and returns this : NameError: name 'Google_Assistant' is not defined

Both French and English codes use Google's STT recognizer to analayse the command given by the user (I've put both samples below).
If it recognizes the expression 'assistant', it will start the Google Assistant

Code for my personal assistant (both Enlgish and French but French doesn't work)

```
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from aiy.board import Board, Led
from aiy.cloudspeech import CloudSpeechClient
from speech_synthesizer import *
from google_assistant import *


def action_test_en(board, args, language, hints, hints2, logging, client, text):


 if 'assistant' in text:
        synthesize_ssml_file(board, language, 
        ''.join(language.code+'/assistant'))
        google_assistant = Google_Assistant(board, language.code2)
        google_assistant.main()
```

Code for the Google Assistant : in a separate python file

```
import logging
import platform
import subprocess
import sys
from google.assistant.library.event import EventType
from aiy.assistant import auth_helpers
from aiy.board import Board, Led
from mygrpc import *

class Google_Assistant:

  def __init__(self, board, language_code):
      self.language_code = language_code
      self.board = board
      print(language_code)
      print(board)


  def main(self):
      logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
      keep_talking = True
      credentials = auth_helpers.get_assistant_credentials()
      assistant = AssistantServiceClient(self.board, self.language_code, 100)
      while keep_talking == True:
          keep_talking = assistant.conversation()




  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

In English the assistant starts but in French I get this in the console output

```
File "/home/pi/Projects/MyAssistant/action_test_fr.py", line 44, in action_test_fr
    google_assistant = Google_Assistant(board, language.code2)
NameError: name 'Google_Assistant' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you importing that `Google_Assistant` class? What is the name of that second file?

Comment: Sounds like you have another `google_assistant.py` somewhere, and it differs from the displayed module that has a `Google_Assistant` class.

Comment: line 44 ?
your script is 17 lines, are you executing the right file ?

Comment: lalam: I have removed the first lines of the action_test_en() method.. They are also if statements that change the language. I removed them because they weren't relevant.    AKX: The class is imported correctly. In fact to make sure I copied the entire content of action_text_en (which handles english requests and works) into action_test_fr (which handles french requests but doesn't work) and the issue remains the same.   TigerhawkT3: What do you mean? I have all the files related to the project in a separate folder